# Calling a list in a different file in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two different files currently (file1.jsx and file2.jsx both in the same directory). file2.jsx depends on the list of file1.jsx, so I want to be able to call the list somehow. This is my current implementation.

file1.jsx:

```
function file1 {
  // this is the list I want to call in file2.jsx
  const [currentSelection, setCurrentSelection] = uuseState([]);
  // also tried export const [currentSelection, setCurrentSelection] = uuseState([]);
  ...
}
```

file2.jsx:

```
//gave me errors
import { currentSelection } from "file1";
function file2 {
  ...
}
```

If I can get some help, I would much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

**State in react-native is internal data-set which affects the rendering of components .It is private and fully controlled by the component .**

However if you want to use value of **currentSelection** in file2 , you can store the value of **currentSelection** in some central store like redux and then fetch it in file2.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you wrote uuseState which should be useState, second for you solution. There are many ways to store an array (assuming that you what to pass to second screen by initial value of your use state is empty array)
You can pass it by react Navigation's params if you are using it,
You can store it using async storage and call that storage on second screen.